# If $X$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}$ and $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, then $\mathbb{E}(\varphi(X, Y) | \mathcal{G}) = \mathbb{E}(\varphi(X, Y))$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation, independence

I'm reading a proposition given without proof in [this](https://ipgold.epfl.ch/%7Eleveque/Lecture_Notes/APA_lecture_notes_1920.pdf) note.

> **Proposition 12.4.** Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-field of $\mathcal{F}, X, Y$ be two random variables such that $X$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}$ and $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, and let $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a Borel-measurable function such that $\mathbb{E}(|\varphi(X, Y)|)<$ $+\infty$. Then
> $$
> \mathbb{E}(\varphi(X, Y) | \mathcal{G}) = \psi(Y) \quad \text { a.s., } \quad \text { where } \psi(y)=\mathbb{E}(\varphi(X, y)).
> $$

It follows from the proposition that $\mathbb{E}(\varphi(X, Y) | \mathcal{G}) = \psi(Y) = \mathbb{E}(\varphi(X, Y))$ is a constant.

Question:

Could you elaborate on how to prove this proposition?

Comment: There should be a proof of this in most texts. See for example chapter 4.1 (maybe 4. 2?) of Durrett PTE 5th edition

Comment: @AndrewZhang [Example 4.1.7.](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf) in Durrett's PTE only contains a special case where $\mathcal G = \sigma(X)$.

Comment: So here we are looking at $Y$ is $\mathcal G$ measurable. This holds for any $\sigma(Y)\subset \mathcal G$. There are some properties about conditional expectation comparing conditioning on $\mathcal G$ versus on $\mathcal F$ where one contains the other. I have a hunch that should do the trick.

Comment: @AndrewZhang You're right. Could you post your comments as an answer?

Comment: See for instance Example 4.1.7 and Theorem 4.1.12,13 of Durrett [PTE](https://services.math.duke.edu/~rtd/PTE/PTE5_011119.pdf)

Comment: What do you mean by $\psi(Y) = \mathbb{E}(\varphi(X, Y))$? They are *different*: $$\psi(Y(\omega))=\mathbf{E}[\varphi(X,y)]_{y=Y(\omega)}=\int_{\Omega}\varphi(X(\eta),Y(\omega))\,\mathbb{P}(\mathrm{d}\eta)$$ but $$\mathbb{E}[\varphi(X,Y)]=\int_{\Omega}\varphi(X(\eta),Y(\eta))\,\mathbb{P}(\mathrm{d}\eta).$$

Comment: @SangchulLee You are right! I should be more careful with the notation, i.e., $\psi(Y) = \mathbb{E}_{X \sim \mathbb P}(\varphi(X, Y))$.

Comment: @AndrewZhang Could you elaborate on your idea of using the Tower property?