# Can we prove that $\mathbb{E}[ \varphi(X, Y) | \mathcal{G}]$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable without knowing that it is equal a.s. to $\psi(Y)$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory, measurable-functions

I have recently come across below [result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4618609/how-to-prove-that-mathbbe-varphix-y-mathcalg-psiy-where-p).

> **Proposition 12.4.** Let $\mathcal{G}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-field of $\mathcal{F}$ and $X, Y$ two random variables such that $X$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}$ and $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable. Let $\varphi: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be Borel-measurable such that $\mathbb{E}[|\varphi(X, Y)|] < \infty$. Then
> $$
> \mathbb{E}[ \varphi(X, Y) | \mathcal{G}] = \psi(Y) \quad \text { a.s.} \quad \text{where} \quad \psi(y) := \mathbb{E}[ \varphi(X, y)].
> $$

A direct consequence is that $\mathbb{E}[ \varphi(X, Y) | \mathcal{G}]$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable.

> Can we prove that $\mathbb{E}[ \varphi(X, Y) | \mathcal{G}]$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable without knowing $\mathbb{E}[ \varphi(X, Y) | \mathcal{G}] = \psi(Y)$?

---

**Update** It seems I was **wrong** in claiming "$\mathbb{E}[ \varphi(X, Y) | \mathcal{G}]$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable".

- Let $Z$ be an integrable random variable. Any version of $\mathbb E[Z | \mathcal G]$ must be $\mathcal G$-measurable in the [standard sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function#Formal_definition).
- Assume $U$ is a random variable such that $\mathbb E[U1_B] = \mathbb E[Z 1_B]$ for all $B \in \mathcal G$. Then $U$ is equal to every version of  $\mathbb E[Z | \mathcal G]$ almost everywhere, but $U$ is not necessarily a version of $\mathbb E[Z | \mathcal G]$.

Comment: I do not think so, excepted if you already know some properties of conditional independence... which are proved in the same way.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan It seems from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4618828/x-is-mathcal-g-measurable-and-x-y-a-s-do-not-imply-y-is-mathcal-g-m?noredirect=1#comment9738993_4618828) thread that I was wrong in claiming $\mathbb{E}[ \varphi(X, Y) | \mathcal{G}]$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable. Could you confirm this?

Comment: Remember that the conditional expectation is defined up to a negligible set. So $\mathbb{E}[ \varphi(X, Y) | \mathcal{G}]$ is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable in the sense that it is almost surely equal to a $\sigma(Y)$-measurable random variable, namely $\psi(Y)$.

Comment: @Will IMHO, if we allow being $\sigma(Y)$-measurable in "the sense" you mentioned, it would cause some confusion. For example, let's consider $\mathbb E[Z | \mathcal G]$ for some random variable $Z$. If $U$ is a random variable such that $\mathbb E[U1_B] = \mathbb E[Z 1_B]$ for all $B \in \mathcal G$. Then $U = \mathbb E[Z | \mathcal G]$ a.s. and thus $U$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable in "the sense" you mentioned, but it's not necessarily $\mathcal G$-measurable in the [standard sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_function#Formal_definition).

Comment: Usually in the definition of the conditional expected value we add that $U$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable. Otherwise $U=Z$ satisfies the condition you mentioned and you would deduce that any random variable is (up to almost sure equality) $\mathcal G$-measurable, which is of course wrong.

Comment: And again, conditional expected value is defined up to a negligible set. There is no such thing as THE conditional expected value. Strictly speaking you must speak of A conditional expected value. With that in mind, speaking of measurability of a conditional expected value can only be meaningful if you allow flexibility up to a negligible set.

Comment: @Will That's exactly what I wanted to say. I meant being $\mathcal G$-measurable in the sense used in the definition of conditional expectation is not the same as being $\mathcal G$-measurable in the sense mentioned in your third comment.

Comment: @Will Any version of $\mathbb E[Z | \mathcal G]$ must be $\mathcal G$-measurable in the standard sense. Assume a random variable $U$ is such that $\mathcal G$-measurable in the sense mentioned in your third comment, and that $\mathbb E[U1_B] = \mathbb E[Z 1_B]$ for all $B \in \mathcal G$. Then $U$ is equal to every version of  $\mathbb E[Z | \mathcal G]$ almost everywhere, but $U$ is not necessarily a version of $\mathbb E[Z | \mathcal G]$. [...]

Comment: [...] My final goal is to verify that $\mathbb{E}[ \varphi(X, Y) | \mathcal{G}]$ is **not** necessarily $\sigma(Y)$-measurable in the standard sense. I'm sorry for being stubborn. I just want to make sure I understand related definitions/concepts correctly...

Comment: If by $\mathbb{E}[ \varphi(X, Y) | \mathcal{G}]$ you mean one of the almost surely equal $\mathcal G$- random variables which satisfy the definition of the conditional expectation, then no it is not necessarily $\sigma(Y)$-measurable. But at least one of them is $\sigma(Y)$-measurable.

Comment: @Analyst $E[\varphi(X,Y)|\mathcal{G}$ is an equivalence class of random variables for the almost sure equality. In this equivalence class, there is at least one measurable $\mathcal{G}$ random variable.

Comment: @Will Thank you so much for your verification! This is exactly what I'm looking for. Could you post your comment as an answer? In my usage, I say $\mathbb{E}[ \varphi(X, Y) | \mathcal{G}]$ satisfies a property if and only every version of $\mathbb{E}[ \varphi(X, Y) | \mathcal{G}]$ satisfies that property.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan by $\mathbb{E}[ \varphi(X, Y) | \mathcal{G}]$, I meant a random variable $Z:\Omega\to \mathbb R$ that satisfies two conditions of conditional expectation. Of course, being $\mathcal G$-measurable does not make sense for an equivalence class.

Comment: My comments did not really answer your question whether it is possible to deduce the measurability without the so called freezing lemma

Comment: @Will You have already confirmed that there are possibly versions of $\mathbb{E}[ \varphi(X, Y) | \mathcal{G}]$ that are not $\sigma(Y)$-measurable in the standard sense...

Comment: Indeed a possible answer could be "We cannot because the version you chose for the conditional expectation might not be $\sigma(Y)$-measurable". But many people would believe I am playing the fool, as they would like an answer to the much more interesting question: "how can we prove that there exists a $\sigma(Y)$-measurable version of the conditional expectation without using the freezing lemma?". Do you see my point?

Comment: @Will I got your point. Anyway, I very appreciate your comments. Thank you so much for your help!